# tomcat running but 404 returns without errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am trying to run my project in tomcat server through tomcat maven plugin.

In my pom xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am running the project through this command in Eclipse:

```
-e clean tomcat:run
```

the server started without errors or warning, but after pasting the url in  web  browser's address bar 404 error occurring(without no errors or warning's in eclipse console).

How can I solve this issue? If you need anything more on it just mention it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` page is not present in write location that is the reason of 404 not found error. please create `index.jsp` or `index.html` into `/src/main/webapp` or `WebContent` folder.

Comment: index.jsp exists in srs/main/webapp folder.

Comment: then check configuration of web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

1.In eclipse tomcat configuration check the "deploy path" basically it is the path path where it will look for war file for deployment
 and if required use custom location  and configure the server path .

2.Please check tomcat-users.xml which I think you have already configured. if not please add below configuration to tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" /> 
<role rolename="manager-script" /> 
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```